# Get the table data content in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table which is created dynamically, I want the table content in an array  means in variable `(like var k = {1.hai 2.me 3.you ....})`. I use this code but this is not a good one

```js
 var x = $("tr[id='1'] > td:nth-child(1)").html()
        x1 = $("tr[id='2'] > td:nth-child(1)").html();
        x2 = $("tr[id='3'] > td:nth-child(1)").html();
        x3 = $("tr[id='4'] > td:nth-child(1)").html();....
        ......
var y=[x,x1,x2,x3,.....................]
```

How can I do this using a loop ?

Comment: Save the contents to an array of objects while the table is created dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you do this:

```
var td=$("table tr td:nth-child(1)"); // get first child of all the td elements

var htmlContent=[]; // initilize an empty array

for(i=0; i<td.length; i++){

    htmlContent[i]=$(td[i]).html(); // add the html content

}
```